# Backbone.js Model not calling success when fetched

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

Having an issue with a Backbone model not calling the success function when data is returned.

Fetch request

```
# Fetch data
@users.fetch({
  success: ->
    alert("test")

  reset: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery was recently upgraded to version 2, downgrade jQuery to less than 2 (eg; jQuery 1.10) and fetch will work again.